# How can I handle errors and continue a LABEL is missing with a GOTO?

Tags: windows, batch-file, label, goto

I'm trying to handle missing label errors in a batch file (Windows 10).  My batch file currently uses a GOTO based on a passed parameter like this:

**MYSCRIPT**.bat *choice1*

I'm trying to do something simple with a simple syntax so that you don't have to include complex menus or lists.  I hoped to do something simple in the batch file such as:

GOTO %1%

The problem occurs when the choice is misspelled, missing (not found.)  I tried some of the examples for similar handling that I found on this site, but I either have the wrong situation or just don't quite understand how to apply it.

I'm sure that at least one person will scold me for not doing it in PowerShell or VBasic or something else.  So I will go ahead and apologize in advance. Frankly, I don't really know how to do what I want to do in any of those. (Some will quip that I don't know how to do it in BATCH either otherwise I wouldn't be asking for help.)

I tried using a "FOR" to parse the file for an instance of the label, and also an "IF ERRORLEVEL 1" but it seems that it's not branching where it needs to go. For instance, if the label is found, go there; if not, go back to the beginning to give an opportunity to input something else.

Thanks in advance for any ideas that might be offered.

Comment: 1 cannot be an environmental variable unless you reference it with delayed expansion. Otherwise the parser thinks it is an argument passed to the script. Regardless of that, we are not here to code for you. We will help you with any existing code you are having trouble with.

Comment: `GoTo %1 2>Nul`

Comment: @Compo: if the label not exists the Batch file just ends. This method only hides the error message...

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to handle this error and continue with `goto` command; just with `call`:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

call :%1 2>NUL
if errorlevel 1 echo Error: label "%1" does not exist
goto :EOF

:one
echo Section one
exit /B

:two
echo Section two
exit /B
```